vue-to-pdf not keeping the font-family
I'm using the vue-to-pdf library to convert a vue component to pdf and export it, but the font family is being ignored. What am I doing wrong?
https://github.com/bandianjuse/vue-to-pdf
<div class="container" ref="box">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="container-text">{{text}}</div>
   </div>
</div>

downloadPdf() {       
    this.$PDFSave(this.$refs['box'], 'pdf')
}  

.container-text {
    font-family: Broadway;
    font-style: italic;
}


@tao please see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-to-pdf?activeTab=readme

Doesn't look like it's possible using this library. Maybe you should look into alternatives?
